# iOS: How to programmatically navigate/jump to different scenes managed by Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a series of views that are managed under a Navigation Controller. Is there a way to programmatically (in iOS5+) jump (push/pop) to different views? For instance, I have

NavigationController->RootViewController->DetailViewController1->DetailViewController2->DetailViewController3

How can I, say, jump from RootViewController to DetailViewController3, and then jump back to DetailViewController1?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the UINavigationController documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

1. Get your VCs from storyboard. (You have to set identifiers in storyboard)

   ```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   UIViewController *DetailViewController1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController1Identifier"];
   UIViewController *DetailViewController3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController3Identifier"];
   ```
2. Push VCs way you need.

   ```
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:(DetailViewController1) animated:YES];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:(DetailViewController3) animated:YES];
   ```

Now, when you press "back" you'll see DetailViewController1.

Comment: My concern is that since I created these views in storyboard, by calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier it will instantiate a new view controller 1 and 3 instead. I would really prefer to utilize a method that can switch to the identified view by name. Anything like that exists?

Comment: Nevermind my comment above. After some messaging of my own code Timur's answer works just fine. Thanks Timur!